# Struct pointers in Cython with GSL Monte-Carlo minimization

Tags: python, pointers, struct, cython, gsl

I'm stuck on this exercise and am not good enough to resolve it. Basically I am writing a Monte-Carlo Maximum Likelihood algorithm for the Bernoulli distribution. The problem is that I have to pass the data as the parameter to the GSL minimization (one-dim) algorithm, and need to also pass the size of the data (since the outer loop are the different sample sizes of the "observed" data). So I'm attempting to pass these parameters as a struct. However, I'm running into seg faults and I'm SURE it is coming from the portion of the code that concerns the struct and treating it as a pointer.

**[EDIT: I have corrected for allocation of the struct and its components]**

```
%%cython

#!python
#cython: boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, nonecheck=False, cdivision=True   

from libc.stdlib cimport rand, RAND_MAX, calloc, malloc, realloc, free, abort
from libc.math cimport log

#Use the CythonGSL package to get the low-level routines
from cython_gsl cimport *

######################### Define the Data Structure ############################

cdef struct Parameters:
    #Pointer for Y data array
    double* Y
    #size of the array
    int* Size

################ Support Functions for Monte-Carlo Function ##################

#Create a function that allocates the memory and verifies integrity
cdef void alloc_struct(Parameters* data, int N, unsigned int flag) nogil:

    #allocate the data array initially
    if flag==1:
        data.Y = <double*> malloc(N * sizeof(double))
    #reallocate the data array
    else:
        data.Y = <double*> realloc(data.Y, N * sizeof(double))

    #If the elements of the struct are not properly allocated, destory it and return null
    if N!=0 and data.Y==NULL:
        destroy_struct(data)
        data = NULL     

#Create the destructor of the struct to return memory to system
cdef void destroy_struct(Parameters* data) nogil:
    free(data.Y)
    free(data)

#This function fills in the Y observed variable with discreet 0/1
cdef void Y_fill(Parameters* data, double p_true, int* N) nogil:

    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i
        double y

    for i in range(N[0]):

        y = rand()/<double>RAND_MAX

        if y <= p_true:
            data.Y[i] = 1 
        else:
            data.Y[i] = 0
#Definition of the function to be maximized: LLF of Bernoulli
cdef double LLF(double p, void* data) nogil:

    cdef:
        #the sample structure (considered the parameter here)
        Parameters* sample

        #the total of the LLF
        double Sum = 0

        #the loop iterator
        Py_ssize_t i, n

    sample = <Parameters*> data

    n = sample.Size[0]

    for i in range(n):

        Sum += sample.Y[i]*log(p) + (1-sample.Y[i])*log(1-p)

    return (-(Sum/n))

########################## Monte-Carlo Function ##############################

def Monte_Carlo(int[::1] Samples, double[:,::1] p_hat, 
                Py_ssize_t Sims, double p_true):

    #Define variables and pointers
    cdef:
        #Data Structure
        Parameters* Data

        #iterators
        Py_ssize_t i, j
        int status, GSL_CONTINUE, Iter = 0, max_Iter = 100 

        #Variables
        int N = Samples.shape[0] 
        double start_val, a, b, tol = 1e-6

        #GSL objects and pointer
        const gsl_min_fminimizer_type* T
        gsl_min_fminimizer* s
        gsl_function F

    #Set the GSL function
    F.function = &LLF

    #Allocate the minimization routine
    T = gsl_min_fminimizer_brent
    s = gsl_min_fminimizer_alloc(T)

    #allocate the struct
    Data = <Parameters*> malloc(sizeof(Parameters))

    #verify memory integrity
    if Data==NULL: abort()

    #set the starting value
    start_val = rand()/<double>RAND_MAX

    try:

        for i in range(N):

            if i==0:
                #allocate memory to the data array
                alloc_struct(Data, Samples[i], 1)
            else:
                #reallocate the data array in the struct if 
                #we are past the first run of outer loop
                alloc_struct(Data, Samples[i], 2)

            #verify memory integrity
            if Data==NULL: abort()

            #pass the data size into the struct
            Data.Size = &Samples[i]

            for j in range(Sims):

                #fill in the struct
                Y_fill(Data, p_true, Data.Size)

                #set the parameters for the GSL function (the samples)
                F.params = <void*> Data
                a = tol
                b = 1

                #set the minimizer
                gsl_min_fminimizer_set(s, &F, start_val, a, b)

                #initialize conditions
                GSL_CONTINUE = -2
                status = -2

                while (status == GSL_CONTINUE and Iter < max_Iter):

                    Iter += 1
                    status = gsl_min_fminimizer_iterate(s)

                    start_val = gsl_min_fminimizer_x_minimum(s)
                    a = gsl_min_fminimizer_x_lower(s)
                    b = gsl_min_fminimizer_x_upper(s)

                    status = gsl_min_test_interval(a, b, tol, 0.0)

                    if (status == GSL_SUCCESS):
                        print ("Converged:\n")
                        p_hat[i,j] = start_val

    finally:
        destroy_struct(Data)
        gsl_min_fminimizer_free(s)
```

with the following python code to run the above function:

```
import numpy as np

#Sample Sizes
N = np.array([5,50,500,5000], dtype='i')

#Parameters for MC
T = 1000
p_true = 0.2

#Array of the outputs from the MC
p_hat = np.empty((N.size,T), dtype='d')
p_hat.fill(np.nan)

Monte_Carlo(N, p_hat, T, p_true)
```

I have separately tested the struct allocation and it works, doing what it should do. However, while funning the Monte Carlo the kernel is killed with an abort call (per the output on my Mac) and the Jupyter output on my console is the following:

```
gsl: fsolver.c:39: ERROR: computed function value is infinite or NaN
```

Default GSL error handler invoked.

It seems now that the solver is not working. I'm not familiar with the GSL package, having used it only once to generate random numbers from the gumbel distribution (bypassing the scipy commands).

I would appreciate any help on this! Thanks

**[EDIT: Change lower bound of a]**

Redoing the exercise with the exponential distribution, whose log likelihood function contains just one log I've honed down the problem having been with `gsl_min_fminimizer_set` initially evaluating at the lower bound of a at 0 yielding the -INF result (since it evaluates the problem prior to solving to generate f(lower), f(upper) where f is my function to optimise). When I set the lower bound to something other than 0 but really small (say the `tol` variable of my defined tolerance) the solution algorithm works and yields the correct results.

Many thanks @DavidW for the hints to get me to where I needed to go.

Comment: Your basic problem is that you never `malloc` `Data` in the function `Monte_Carlo`, so you end up using a pointer that doesn't point to anything. I don't think it's too hard to fix but it doesn't look hugely easy for me else to set up and test...

Comment: @DavidW Totally correct. I restructured the code to allocate the struct and then implement functions to allocate the elements of the struct and to free the memory. On its own, the struct works (I have updated the code to account for it). However, when I try to run the cython code, the kernel dies saying that abort was called (I use abort if the struct or any of its elements are not properly allocated). When I remove this verification of memory allocation, the code then kills the kernel from a GSL error on an infinite solution. Likely, again from a problem in allocating the struct.

Comment: What do you do to ensure 0<p<1? That would give you an invalid answer.

Comment: In this portion of the code, 'gsl_min_fminimizer_set(s, &F, start_val, a, b)' I constrain the interval with a=0 and b=1 (or at least, this is what I think it's doing). I am now going to work on this section of the GSL section of the code separately with a far simpler exercise to better understand how these routines work. It turns out the the abort call is no longer coming from the struct allocation as this was fixed, but rather because from the GSL routine's inability to find a bounded solution.

Comment: I don't think this is the function of the a, b in the `gal_min_fminimizer_set` routine. I will transform p to be within the bounds 0 and 1 instead.

Comment: I've posted an answer which is my best guess at the issue. I really can't easily test it though so it is a guess! Good luck

Comment: Many thanks. Your help has pointed me towards bettering it. This code really is just practice code for a much more involved econometric problem, so understanding how these tools work in "simpler" examples really helps me move along.

Comment: @DavidW, the problem was stemming from `gsl_min_fminimizer_set` evaluating at a=0, as its initial evaluation of the function to optimize to generate f(a=lower), f(b=upper) yielded the `-INF`. I set the lower bound to `tol`, the tolerance I specify for the algorithm and I get a working algorithm. Many Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working. (It's more helpful for anyone else having the same problem if you answer your own question rather than edit the solution into the question - just easier to read).

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat speculative answer since I don't have GSL installed so struggle to test it (so apologies if it's wrong!)

---

I think the issue is the line

```
Sum += sample.Y[i]*log(p) + (1-sample.Y[i])*log(1-p)
```

It looks like `Y[i]` can be either 0 or 1. When `p` is at either end of the range 0-1 it gives `0*-inf = nan`. In the case where only all the 'Y's are the same this point is the minimum (so the solver will reliably end up at the invalid point). Fortunately you should be able to rewrite the line to avoid getting a `nan`:

```
if sample.Y[i]:
   Sum += log(p)
else:
   Sum += log(1-p)
```

(the case which will generate the `nan` is the one not executed).

---

There's a second minor issue I've spotted: in `alloc_struct` you do `data = NULL` in case of an error. This only affects the local pointer, so your test for `NULL` in `Monte_Carlo` is meaningless. You'd be better returning a true or false flag from `alloc_struct` and checking that. I doubt if you're hitting this error though.

---

**Edit**: Another better option would be to find the minimum analytically: the derivative of `A log(p) + (1-A) log (1-p)` is `A/p - (1-A)/(1-p)`. Average all the `sample.Y`s to find `A`. Finding the place where the derivative is 0 gives `p=A`. *(You'll want to double-check my working!)*. With this you can avoid having to use the GSL minimization routines.

Comment: Thanks for your response!! Yes, I do believe that the problem is essentially the possibility of the bounded constraint on p as you previously pointed out. I was thinking of transforming the variable so that it is between 0<p<1. I will fix the second check with a true/false flag.

Comment: Yes, your analytical derivative is correct and is the Maximum-Liklihood estimator for the Bernoulli distribution. My goal is to learn how to use the GSL solver, which is why i'm trying to do it numerically and then compare to the analytical solution :-)